# How to get image Type In PHAsset(PNG or JPG)?

Tags: ios

In iOS8 and later, i get images at this code:

```
    PHFetchOptions *option = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
    option.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
    PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:_collection options:option];

    [result enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if (((PHAsset *)obj).mediaType == PHAssetMediaTypeImage) {

            PHCachingImageManager *imageManager = [[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init];
            PHAsset *asset = obj;
            PHImageRequestOptions * options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
            options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
            options.synchronous = YES;


            [imageManager requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:options resultHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable imageData, NSString * _Nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
                /*******/
                /* Now I get image type in here with imageDate*/
                /* I just want JPG type Image*/
            }];
        }
    }];
```

But in this code, I need a lot of time, So how can I get Image Type with PHAsset and don't use requestImageData

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cant get the image type by PHAsset.But you can get it by CIImage's property properties(properties is the name of a property)